# Calling for a column in a dataframe

Tags: paste

I'm creating a dataframe(df) with two, columns PEA_0 and PEA_180. To input values in the cells of each column I could do this:

```
df$PEA_0 <-1
df$PEA_180 <-1
```

But since I'm expanding my df I would like a easy way to change the number behind "PEA_". I would like to assign the number to a letter so that I could change the number on the fly later:

```
a<-0
b<-180
```

and run the code like this:

```
paste("df$PEA_", a, sep="") < -1
```

I want R to understand that the code above means:
`df$PEA_0 <- 1` but R only sees `"df$PEA_0" <- 1` and throws the error :
*Error in paste("tilst$Death_", a) <- 1 :
target of assignment expands to non-language object*

Any thoughts on how to omit this?